# Multiple identities knock each other out

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

I'm using IdentityPart and "Identifier" to create import ID's for many different content types, co I can reimport same content and just have it update existing records. This however stops working for content types that have parts that define own identifiers like AutoroutePart creates identity "alias" and thus completely knocks out ability to use "Identifier"

I've tracked it to this code in Autoroute's ContentHandler

```
// Register alias as identity
OnGetContentItemMetadata<AutoroutePart>((ctx, part) => {
    if (part.DisplayAlias != null)
    {
        ctx.Metadata.Identity.Add("alias", part.DisplayAlias);
    }
});
```

If i delete this and recompile, "Identifier" starts working again. But I lose ability to use "alias". Is there a way to add "alias" as identity without interfering with other parts that add their own identities?

Comment: Why? The alias identity already guarantees that your scenario works, so why do you need to add your own identity? And why would it matter which identity is used?

Comment: Hey, It matters because I want to import "products" from the inventory tracking software (I'm generating the XML for import myself), only way for me to get the alias is to extract it from the product name. But if product is renamed (like new revision is released), I wouldn't be able to create matching alias, Identifier would work better as it's a background variable and thus can use product catalog number (which remains constant). In the ID you use selector Id="/alias=" or Id="/Identifier=" if you can use only one then why not simply use Id="someidentity" ... it would work better

Comment: Also all identities are included in the export both alias and Identifier, so what determines which identity provider takes priority on the import? 2 parts, 2 identities, 1 randomly selected identity working?

Comment: That should still work: while importing, it should match the identities declared in your import file with what's already in the system. The id is like a wallet. It may have several forms of id, like you may have a driver's license, an id card, a library card, etc. but any one of those should be enough to prove your identity. That there is more than one should be irrelevant.
How exactly does it fail in your case? (this might be a bug)

Comment: Maybe I haven't made myself clear enough sorry. If I add IdentityPart to a content type's definition I can use Identifier, but when I add AutoroutePart, Identifier stops working and then only alias works. So using AutoroutePart makes IdentityPart to not work at all for proving identity. If I remove AutoroutePart, Identifier from IdentityPart works again (or if i remove mentioned code from AutoroutePart).

Comment: I'm investigating it.

Comment: So I was able to reproduce the problem, and I have a fix that I'll push into the 1.x branch once I've written a couple tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in the way identities are matched during import. A single identity token in the import file should be enough to ensure a match with existing content items in the system. The behavior was that a full match of all identity tokens was required. I fixed that in changeset https://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/1540f69a79a843182d19936148b3bbd9c5781374 (1.x branch). It should be available in Orchard 1.9.